# Firebase auth rest api using axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, axios

I am trying to use Firebase REST API with Axios on Rect Native project:

No matter what I do... I always receive the same error:

```
handleLogin = () => {
        //alert('trying to login....');
        const onSuccess = ({ data }) => {
            alert('Success!!!!');
            // Set JSON Web Token on success
            //setClientToken(data.token);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, isAuthorized: true });
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        };

        const onFailure = (error) => {
            alert('Error!!!!');
            console.log(error && error.response);
            this.setState({ errors: error.response.data, isLoading: false });
        };
        const signupUser = async () => {
            try {
                // set the url
                const url =
                    'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=.............';
                // request data object
                const data = {
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password,
                    returnSecureToken: true,
                };

                // set the headers
                const config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                };

                const res = await axios.post(url, data, config);
                console.log(res.data);
                onSuccess(res.data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                onFailure(err);
            }
        };
        signupUser();
    };
```

I am always receiving error 400 with the same response:

"code": 400,
      "errors": Array [
        Object {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
          "reason": "invalid",

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody need this....

here was a problem:

```
const config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                };
```